Origin(s) of the notion of infinity
It is very common to attribute the origin of the notion of infinity to the Greeks (the Greek miracle). Now, some scholars in ethnomathematics argue that the origin may be older and from another civilization from which the Greeks drew inspiration: the Egyptian civilization, with, for example, the symbol of the ouroboros: https://journals.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/index.php/aegyp/article/view/66091

My question is: are there good references on the origins of the concept of infinity?

Seppänen, J. (2000). Infinity - An Outline of Conceptions in Mythology, Cosmology and Natural Philosophy. In  Finite versus infinite: contributions to an eternal dilemma. . Springer pp. 257-283.

@Mauricio, whsat exactly? it is rendered ok to me.
